# How can I control the font size of each chapter's and section's title separately?

Tags: fontsize

My question is how can I control the font size of each chapter's and section's title? I tried `\Large`, `\normalsize` `\small` etc. But i am not satisfied, since I would like to control the font size exactly to a number, such as font size 16, 16.5, 17, etc. Could anyone tell how to achieve this? Thanks!!

Comment: Any answer on this would heavily depend on the `documentclass` used, since many of them bring their own mechanism to alter the appearance. So i suggest that you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/232#232)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The font size can be changed with

```
\fontsize{size}{skip} \selectfont
```

where size is the font size ans skip is the baseline skip (typically 1.2 times the font size).

If you want to know how to use that to change headers, you have to indicate which document class you are using.

However, I do not recommend fiddling with the font size to the point. Usually, the document class sets appropriate sizes that harmonize with each other.